# Userform disable all fields

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform that can be filled in but only if a previous userform was filled in as there are calculations in the userform based on the previous input and if those are empty, the calculations crash.

Now I did write a few if statements that check for these empty values and then had a brain flash.. how about if one of the fields is missing, the userform is just disabled. So thought, so done and it works :)

```
if DP1 = "" then
reportback.enable = false
else
end if
```

That is the form and it shows up beautifully and nothing can be changed, but Ohhh.. you can´t even close the form, nothing works .. lol.

So my question. Is there a way to disable all fields from any input but still have the cancel button active ?

```
Private Sub Cancel_Click()
Unload reportback
End Sub
```

Comment: Not too clear for me ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below code to disable all controls on your form to avoid the issue.
UserForm1 refers to name of Userform kindly replace accordingly.

```
Dim ctrl As Control

For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
    ctrl.Enabled = False
Next

Set ctrl = Nothing
```

Comment: Tx. would never have figured it out myself.